# Given a .net control, can I get the tooltip?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a .net control (ok, a lot of them). I can invoke methods on any given control, but cannot create new controls or access static methods of the classes I don't have controls for. I don't have access to any tooltip objects. Is there any way I can get the tooltip object for a given control?

(We're using a rather restricted test automation framework in Java to access controls on an application written in C#.net, is the background behind this odd query)

ETA: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I'm not trying to set a tooltip, I'm trying to **get** the existing tooltip. And I can't create new controls so anything that includes `new Foo()` isn't going to work.

Comment: The underlying Windows message is TTM_GETTOOLINFO.  You'll get a TOOLINFO filled if the control supports a tooltip.  There's no control method for that.

Comment: @HansPassant Your comment is more helpful than any of the current answers. I'm intrigued.

Comment: I understand the question well enough to know I can't answer it.  No idea what a "restricted test automation framework in Java" can do.

Comment: @HansPassant Invoke methods and fetch properties on controls :( I think the answer is "you can't do what you want to do here", so I'll have to dig deeper into alternate methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this is not possible. :( To get the tooltip for a control, I need access to the ToolTip class, which is fine if I'm programming the controls but otherwise not really exposed.

Answer (score 4):

```
string text = toolTip1.GetToolTip(yourControl);
```

This gives you the text on the tooltip for yourControl.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.textBox1, "Hello");
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a Popup Event.  Below, the code is getting the value set for the tooltip and also displaying it an status textbox on the MDIForm.

```
    private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        Control TheControl = e.AssociatedControl;
        cls_Global.gf_MDIForm.DisplayMsg(this.toolTip1.GetToolTip(TheControl) + "");
    }
```