# Getting a .net tooltip from RFT

Tags: .net, tooltip, rft

Using Rational Functional Tester, I need to verify the tooltip objects created in .net. I can use reflection to invoke methods on .net controls I have found using RFT, but there [doesn't seem to be a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235387/given-a-net-control-can-i-get-the-tooltip) to get the tooltip object associated with the control from the control itself. Is there some special RFT method that can fetch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the secret is that there's only one tooltip object which updates its text based on what control the mouse is currently hovering over.

It is not a child or descendent of the application it belongs to, but instead an Owned Object. 
The actual owned object has a class that looks like nonsense; ours was "WindowsForms10.tooltips_class32.app.0.33c0d9d". I suspect this is because it's actually a win32 object, not a .net object. This object has a child with class ".Tooltip", which has a property ".text" containing the tooltip text.